# Automorphism group of the cycle graph with $k$ diagonals

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-groups, polygons

Let $C_n$ be the cycle graph on $n$ vertices. Then $Aut(C_n) \cong D_{2n}$ the dihedral group of order $n$.

Now, let $C_{n,i}$ be the cycle graph with $i$ many diagonals connecting opposite vertices added one by one in a "nice" order. In the extream, the cycle graph with all such diagonals has automorphism group $\mathbb{z}_n$ the group consists only of rotations in $D_{2n}$.

I want to know, what is the automorphism group of $C_{n,i}$?. Also, is there a nice order in adding diagonals to $C_n$ so that the automorphism group of the resulting graphs has some inclusion property?

Thank you.

Comment: If I add all diagonals to $C_4$ or $C_6$ then the resulting group is not only the rotations.

Comment: @GordonRoyle Sorry. That was my guess. Is it something bigger than $D_{2n}$?

Comment: If you add *all* diagonals to $C_n$, shouldn't you end up with the complete graph $K_n$ with automorphism group $S_n$?

Comment: If you start with a cycle $C_n$ and add a single edge, you will end up at automorphism group $\Bbb Z_2$ or $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$, both subgroups of $D_{2n}$. There are not much more groups contained in these, so I think you cannot obtain any surprising sequences of groups in that way. (I under stood your question in the way that you want an increasing or decreasing sequence of automorphism groups)

Comment: Thank you. Now I am understanding where I am wrong. I am adding diagonals between the opposite pair of vertices only. So if you add all such diagonals the resulting graph won't be complete.  Thanks.

Comment: @GA316 So, your $n$ should be even, as otherwise there are no such diagonals. And still, when you add all of these diagonals, you have automorphism group $D_{2n}$ or larger.

Comment: @M.Winter yes. Thank you. I realized this earlier itself but I forget to edit that part of the question. Sorry for this. If we assume $n$ even and keep adding the diagonals is there any hope for some inclusion relation?

Comment: @GA316 Can you say more about what exactly you mean by "inclusion relation"? As I explained in an earlier comment, there are no exciting purely decreasing/increasing chains of automorphism groups.

Comment: @M.Winter Sorry. My precise question is, how adding more and more diagonals will affect the automorphism groups?

Comment: @GA316 This is highly dependent on the exact order in which you add the edges. It is hard to make a general statement. If you start with a highly symmetric pattern and end with a highly symmetric pattern, there will be lots of non-symmetric pattern in between. What one could answer here is a list of possible automorphism groups of such a graph. Would this be of interest?

Comment: @M.Winter Hmm. Thank you. I can see your point through small examples. I can calculate the possible automorphism groups for small groups and if you have some idea about these groups kindly share with me. Thanks a really lot for your comments. I had a good time discussing with you :) .

Comment: @GA316 I hade some thought on the possible automorphism groups, and what I found so far are the following: $S_4, \Bbb Z_2,\Bbb Z_2^2,\Bbb Z_2\rtimes \Bbb Z_2^2$ as well as certain $D_{4k}$ and $C_{2k}$ for divisors $k\mid n$ (and the cyclic group, only if $n/k\ge 6$). However, nothing here is proven, these are just considerations. Therefore no answer yet.

Comment: @M.Winter Dear Winter, Thanks a lot. This helped me a lot with my computations. With a little bit of my sage knowledge and also with your suggestion I have made some progress in this direction. Thank you :)